# Get minimum value for each group by multiple subgroups

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, aggregate, minimum

I am using R and have a data table like the following below.  The values of **var1** and **var2** are contextually related (ordered ascending by **var1**) for each row, whilst **var3** is the cumulative total of **var3** for each group (by **g1**, **g2**, **g3**).  **var4** is a variable broken into stacking tenths (there are 10 rows per group in the data).

**The Problem**

EDIT: For each value of var4, I need to calculate the minimum of **var1** from the minimum of all **var3** that is >= each **var4**?

I have millions of rows of this type of data, so performance is important

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Old Question: For each row: If **var4** < minimum of all **var3** for the group, the minimum of all **var1** should be returned. If **var4** > the minimum of all **var 3**, then the minimum **var1** from the rows with the maximum **var3** that is <= **var4** should be returned.

```
g1(char) g2(POSIXct)          g3(int)  var1(num) var2(num) var3(num) var4(num)
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30     -100       1661      1661       280
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30        0          0      1661       560
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       57        720      2381       840
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       59          0      2381      1120
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       70          0      2381      1400
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       77          0      2381      1680
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       91         80      2461      1960
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       93          0      2461      2240
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       95          0      2461      2520
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       99        340      2801      2800
```

The expected results for one group would look like this:

```
g1(char) g2(POSIXct)          g3(int)  var1   var2   var3   var4  var5
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30     -100    1661   1661    280  -100
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30        0       0   1661    560  -100
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       57     720   2381    840  -100  
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       59       0   2381   1120  -100
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       70       0   2381   1400  -100
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       77       0   2381   1680    57
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       91      80   2461   1960    57
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       93       0   2461   2240    57
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       95       0   2461   2520    99
A        01/01/2019 04:30:00  -30       99     340   2801   2800    99
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The OP already brings an example and also tells us its expected output.

Comment: hi your column, g2 is truncated. do you mind filling in the details so that the groups are explicit?

Comment: An example datetime is 01/01/2019 04:30:00 for all rows in this group.  I'll update the code as soon as I am able to

Comment: I have updated the question and the sample code to re-clarify the question

Answer (score 3):

Two possible approaches using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# option 1
DT[, var5 := min(var1) * (var4 <= min(var3)), by = .(g1, g2, g3)
   ][, var5 := replace(var5, var5 == 0, min(var1)), by = .(g1, g2, g3, var3)][]

# option 2
DT[, var5 := min(var1) * (var4 <= min(var3)), by = .(g1, g2, g3)
   ][, var1min := min(var1), by = .(g1, g2, g3, var3)
     ][var5 == 0, var5 := var1min, by = .(g1, g2, g3, var3)
       ][, var1min := NULL][]
```

which both give:

> ```
> > DT
>     g1            g2  g3 var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
>  1:  A 01/01/2019... -30   50 1000 1000  200   50
>  2:  A 01/01/2019... -30   55    0 1000  400   50
>  3:  A 01/01/2019... -30   57    0 1000  600   50
>  4:  A 01/01/2019... -30   59  100 1100  800   50
>  5:  A 01/01/2019... -30   70    0 1100 1000   50
>  6:  A 01/01/2019... -30   77    0 1100 1200   59
>  7:  A 01/01/2019... -30   91  200 1300 1400   91
>  8:  A 01/01/2019... -30   93  250 1550 1600   93
>  9:  A 01/01/2019... -30   95    0 1550 1800   93
> 10:  A 01/01/2019... -30   99  450 2000 2000   99
> ```

---

Used data:

```
DT <- fread("g1   g2     g3  var1  var2  var3  var4  var5
A        01/01/2019...  -30      50    1000  1000   200  50
A        01/01/2019...  -30      55       0  1000   400  50
A        01/01/2019...  -30      57       0  1000   600  50
A        01/01/2019...  -30      59     100  1100   800  50
A        01/01/2019...  -30      70       0  1100  1000  50
A        01/01/2019...  -30      77       0  1100  1200  59
A        01/01/2019...  -30      91     200  1300  1400  91
A        01/01/2019...  -30      93     250  1550  1600  93
A        01/01/2019...  -30      95       0  1550  1800  93
A        01/01/2019...  -30      99     450  2000  2000  99")[, var5 := NULL]
```

Comment: What if, for each value of var4, I need to calculate the minimum of var1 from the minimum of all var3 that is >= each var4? I have edited the sample code to show the expected results, but I was unable to modify your code to reach this solution.